# Using Butter Knife library for view injection

Tags: android, butterknife

**What i am doing**::

1. I am trying to run [butter knife library](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) for my simple project
2. I have followed all the steps in documentation, but still i am
   getting log errors
3. How can i resolve this, am i missing any step
4. I have also added the jar in libs folder

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.butterknife;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @InjectView(R.id.txtID) TextView title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        title.setText("Hello Everyone !!");

    }
}
```

**Log**::

```
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.butterknife/com.example.butterknife.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at com.example.butterknife.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
04-15 11:50:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  ... 11 more
04-15 11:51:06.722: I/Process(913): Sending signal. PID: 913 SIG: 9
```

Comment: looks like `title` is null, it hasn't been injected with anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Follow this Steps [ into Eclipse IDE ]:

1)Right click on your project withIn Package Explorer. Got to `Java Compiler` --> `Annotation Processing` and check the `Enable project specific settings`.

2)Expand the `Annotation Processing` section and select `Factory Path`. Check `Enable project specific settings` and then click `Add JARs` Navigate to the project's libs/ folder and select the `ButterKnife` jar.

3)Click `Ok` to save the new settings. `Eclipse` will ask you to rebuild your project to which you should click `Yes`.

**Note:** Make sure that the `.apt_generated/` folder is in your project root. It should contain files like `YOURACTIVITY$$ViewInjector.java`. If these files are not present trigger a clean build by selected Project → Clean. This folder and files should not be checked into revision control.

**Reference** -> [Set up manual configuration for ButterKnife annotations](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ide-eclipse.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me on the Documentation ... I was able to resolve it [+1] too !

Comment: @Casper Love to Help :)

Comment: The Annotation Processing option didn't exist in my Eclipse installation had to follow the work around here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26028701/329034

Comment: There is no such thing as `Java Compiler` there.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky This is for eclipse.For studio check this out.
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations

Comment: Not working for me =( I followed the steps in Eclipse, but from the **Note: "Make sure that the .apt_generated/ folder is in your project root..."** - I do not see any folder named `apt-generated` in my project root, and the errors don't go away.

Answer (score 3):

> IntelliJ IDEA — If your project uses an external configuration (like a
>   Maven pom.xml) then annotation processing should just work.

Follow these steps :

1. Open IDEA's preference: `File` -> `Other Settings` -> `Default Settings`
2. Navigate to `Compiler` -> `Annotation Processors` Then Check `Enable annotation processing`

Reference ->  [Set up manual configuration for ButterKnife annotations](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ide-idea.html)

**Update 30-6-2015**

Follow These Steps for `Intellij` IDEA 14.0 :

1. Open IDEA's preference: `File` -> `Settings`  or click `ctl + alt + s`
2. Navigate to `Build, Execution and deployment` -> `Compiler` -> `Annotation Processors` and Choose your project Then Check `Enable annotation processing`

Comment: It may be better to use File - Settings instead of File - Default Settings. And for IntelliJ IDEA 14.1 the settings dialog has gotten one level deeper, so it's Build, Execution, Deployment - Compiler - Annotation Processors.

Comment: It isn't an option anymore.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky open `Compiler` tab, and choose `Annotation Processors` .

Another Way: open `Setting` Dialog and search for `Annotation Processors`

Comment: @ahmedhamdy Unfortunately this is not an option in the latest Canary build of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

@Bind replaces @InjectView and @InjectViews.
ButterKnife.bind and ButterKnife.unbind replaces ButterKnife.inject and ButterKnife.reset, respectively.

look at this : [@InjectView replaced ...](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/f65dc849d80f6761d1b4a475626c568b2de883d9/CHANGELOG.md)