# The import butterknife.InjectView cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, butterknife

I am trying to use [this library project](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view), so I tried to run the sample application (in `/app/source/main/` in the Github link), and in `MainActivity.java`, I am getting the error on the import

```
import butterknife.InjectView;
```

and also in `MainActivity.java` and `VerticalLinearRecyclerViewSample.java`, at every occurance of `@InjectView(...)` annotation, I get the following error:

```
InjectView cannot be resolved to a type
```

**So what should I do about this?**

---

**WHAT I TRIED:**

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076103/using-butter-knife-library-for-view-injection). Didn't work for me, left a comment there.

I have [followed these steps to include the Butter Knife library](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ide-eclipse.html) till Step#3. About Step#4, *"Make sure that the .apt_generated/ folder is in your project root..."* - this project does not have any folder named `.apt-generated` or something in the project root folder.

---

**Note:** I actually use Eclipse, and the project on Github is for Android Studio, so I created a new project in eclipse and copied individual files from the downloaded Android Studio project. I hope this does not made a difference.

Comment: Which version of ButterKnife you are using? Latest version has bind instead of InjectView. Version before that, uses ButterKnife.inject(this) to inject view. Also, Eclipse is not supported anymore, start using Android Studio.

Comment: @Sharj v7.0.1 downloaded from this page. `@Bind` works, thank you so very much. If you can post it as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Credit to @Sharj for answering first.

The Butterknife 7.0.0 release included the breaking change of renaming of the annotation verbs. This is highlighted in the changelog and reflected in the website.

```
Version 7.0.0 *(2015-06-27)*
----------------------------

 * `@Bind` replaces `@InjectView` and `@InjectViews`.
 * `ButterKnife.bind` and `ButterKnife.unbind` replaces `ButterKnife.inject` 
    and `ButterKnife.reset`, respectively.
...
```

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/f65dc849d80f6761d1b4a475626c568b2de883d9/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: poor Object oriented...changing the annotation breaks app if done a automated build

Comment: Late response here, but the change in API was done as part of the 7.x.x Major release so it is allowed under semantic versioning.
http://semver.org/

Answer (score 8):

Latest version has `bind` instead of `InjectView`. Version before that, uses `ButterKnife.inject(this)` to inject view. Also, Eclipse is not supported anymore, start using Android Studio.

Comment: Hi, I really wanted to accept your answer. But the answer by Derek (in which they have accredited your answer) is more descriptive and slightly more comprehensive. So I asked a question on meta stack exchange about which one to accept, and got the advice that I should accept the one which will be more helpful to the community. So I could only upvote your answer. I would upvote more if I could. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Hey. Im still working on Eclipse. Is there any way of importing ButterKnife on there?

Answer (score 7):

`@InjectView` is no more available and is replaced by `@BindView`. We will have to import `Butterknife` dependencies to use the `annotations`.

Comment: This answers the question without mistake ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Change ButterKnife.inject(this); to ButterKnife.bind(this);

Answer (score 0):

Try add:`implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'` in your `build.gradle`