# error: cannot find symbol class InjectView

Tags: java, android

[how to resolve this? I try to input butterknife injectview, but it can't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0q0q.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe since the Butterknife 7.0.0 release the @InjectView annotation has been replaced with @Bind annotation. 
As this older answer shows :[The import butterknife.InjectView cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531475/the-import-butterknife-injectview-cannot-be-resolved)