# NullPointerException with using ButterKnife

Tags: android, butterknife

I enable annotation processing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26741086/5322183) and follow this code:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements WeatherUpdater.AsyncResponse {

@BindView(R.id.temperature_max) TextView temperature_max;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    temperature_max.setText("NULL POINTER!");
...
return view;
}
}
```

I have complex structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout>

                <TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/temperature_max"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            ...
</ScrollView>
```

This LOGCAT:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.my.app, PID: 22813
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.ui.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5158)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                   at com.my.app.ui.fragment.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.java:28)
                                                   at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
                                                   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:685)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5319)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2190)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5158) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566) 
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Oh, yeah, I use this gradle version -> 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'

But I don't know why arise NullPointerException. I searched through Internet in search of a problem, but solutions and have not found. Does anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: what problem for `TextView temperature_max = ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.temperature_max);`

Comment: If he were to use it, based on his complex View Hierarchy that would add a lot of boilerplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to **Return** your **View**.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements WeatherUpdater.AsyncResponse {

@BindView(R.id.temperature_max) TextView temperature_max;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    temperature_max.setText("NULL POINTER!");
    return view; // This need to be return.
}
}
```

**Edit 1 :**

`@Bind` replaces `@InjectView` and `@InjectViews`. `ButterKnife.bind` and `ButterKnife.unbind` replaces `ButterKnife.inject` and `ButterKnife.reset`  respectively.

**And Also Add this.**

```
TextView temperature_max = ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.temperature_max);
```

Look at this Reference [Here.](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/f65dc849d80f6761d1b4a475626c568b2de883d9/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: oh, no, I fogrot to print "return view;" in post. Edit post.

Answer (score -2):

You should use `@Bind` instead of `@BindView`. Everything else is fine.

Comment: Butterknife 8.0.1 uses `@BindView` instead of `@Bind`

Comment: @Eixx ok. I am still on some old version. Thanks for correcting me.