# Can't resolve symbol BindViews in Butterknife

Tags: android, android-studio, butterknife

I am using Butterknife to bind a views.When Binding group multiple views
like [Acting on Multiple Views In a List](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Reducing-View-Boilerplate-with-Butterknife#1-acting-on-multiple-views-in-a-list) , `@BindViews` can't available. See below image:

[image]

I am trying below code:

```
@BindViews({ R.id.edtOne, R.id.edtTwo, R.id.edtThree })
List<EditText> editTextsList;
```

How can I resolved it?

Comment: Yes thanks. But I want to use `@BindViews` with multiple views(Here EditText) as per given link is my question.

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977646/nullpointerexeption-with-using-butterknife/36977769#36977769

Answer (score 9, accepted):

make sure you update to latest version of ButterKnife:

Version 8.0.0 (2016-04-25)

```
@Bind becomes @BindView and @BindViews (one view and multiple views, respectively).
```

Answer (score 4):

From **`Version 7.0.0`** It has changed.

`@Bind` replaces `@InjectView` and `@InjectViews`. `ButterKnife.bind` and `ButterKnife.unbind` replaces `ButterKnife.inject` and `ButterKnife.reset` respectively.

Look at this Reference  [Link](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/f65dc849d80f6761d1b4a475626c568b2de883d9/CHANGELOG.md).

**And from `Version 8.0.0`.**

The runtime and compiler are now split into two artifacts.

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.0'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.0'
```

Look at this [Link](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-800-2016-04-25) Also.

Comment: Have you checked it Brother ?

Answer (score 2):

Try in app module

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```